# What sort of equation produces this upside-down hockey stick shaped curve?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a dataset that I'm trying to model with an equation.  The points when connected produce a curve much like an upside down hockey stick:

[image]

I've been experimenting with an inverse square root equation y = b - a/sqrt(x).  Below model uses a=100 and b=10.  However I can't get the curve to turn sharply enough.

[image]

Am I on the right track?  How can improve the fit?

Comment: Looks like it could be logarithmic to me, try $y = a + b\log(x).$

Comment: Use a higher negative exponent on $x$ in the second term, maybe?

Comment: Have you tried plotting your data on a semi-log or log-log plot?

Comment: something like this? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/brkxdclthl

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k05plkvo4p is the closest i've been able to get so far.

Answer (score 1):

Part of what was throwing me off was the *upside-down*-ness of the curve.  This is also what was preventing Excel from coming up with a regression equation.

After realizing this, I made a new plot with the Y values subtracted from 10 which flipped it back over.  Excel was then able to fit it to a power regression curve with equation y = a * x^b, where b was negative.